# My program not work as expected

Tags: c, file-io

I need to find the position of some strings. These strings are stored in a file named `queryfile` , from an other file named `datafile`.

However, my program does not work as expected.
Can some one help me?

My program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *queryfile;
    queryfile = fopen("op2query.txt","r");

    FILE *datafile;
    datafile = fopen("op2data.txt","r" );

    int i = 1;
    char word[99];
    char search[99];

    if(queryfile==NULL) {
      printf("Error in reading Query File");
      exit(1);
    }
    if(datafile==NULL) {
      printf("Error in reading Data File");
      exit(1);
    } 

     while(fscanf(queryfile,"%98s",search)==1){  
         while(fscanf(datafile,"%98s",word)==1){
             if (strcmp(word,search)==0){
                 printf("\n %i %s ", i, search);
                 rewind(datafile);
                 i=1;
                 break;
              }
              else 
                 i++;   
         }
     }

    fclose(datafile);
    fclose(queryfile);
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build an array of each set of words to be tested, by splitting the query string into words. These words can span a line break in the data file. I mark the data file position on the second word of the set, if the search fails I seek to that point (if necessary). The program succeeds even if I duplicate every word "age" in the data file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXWORDS    5
#define MAXLEN      99

int main()
{
    int j, i, done, words, count;
    long mark;
    char word[MAXLEN];
    char search[MAXLEN];
    char *tok, *sptr[MAXWORDS];
    FILE *queryfile;
    FILE *datafile;

    if ((queryfile = fopen("op2query.txt","r")) == NULL) {
         printf("Error in reading Query File");
         exit(1);
    }
    if ((datafile = fopen("op2data.txt","r" )) == NULL) {
         printf("Error in reading Data File");
         exit(1);
    } 

    while(fgets(search, MAXLEN, queryfile) != NULL){
        words = 0;
        done = 0;
        count = 0;
        mark = -1;
        tok = strtok(search, " \r\n");
        while (tok && words < MAXWORDS) {       // build array of query
            sptr[words++] = tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, " \r\n");        // strips newline too
        }
        if (words < 1)                          // no more queries
            break;
        rewind(datafile);                       // beginning of file

        while (!done) {                         // until none to read
            count++;
            if (mark >= 0)                      // when more than one word to search
                fseek (datafile, mark, SEEK_SET);
            mark = -1;
            for (j=0; j<words; j++) {
                if (j == 1)                     // mark for next search
                    mark = ftell(datafile);
                if (fscanf(datafile, "%98s", word) != 1){
                    done = 1;                   // end of file
                    break;
                }
                if (strcmp(sptr[j], word)!=0)
                    break;                      // failed multi word search
            }
            if (done) 
                printf("NOT FOUND!");
            else if (j == words) {              // if all words found
                printf("%d", count);
                done = 1;                       // success
            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<words; i++)
            printf(" %s", sptr[i]);             // show array of words asked
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(datafile);
    fclose(queryfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
18 wisdom
40 season
NOT FOUND! summer
22 age of foolishness
```

**UPDATE** - I print `NOT FOUND!` when query not found. Added "summer" to query file.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! But what should I do If i want to tell the user that the query they want to find are not in the text. Let say `winter` are in the query file and I want to show `NOT FOUND! winter`. Thank you so much !

Comment: @tatatatat have a look.

Answer (score 0):

you should put some debug-output behind the fscanf-calls (like `printf("search:<%s> word:<%s>", search, word);`

Then you will see, that fscanf stops at finding a white-space. you compare `wisdom` to each consecutive word in op2data.txt.

You should read line by line with `fgets()` removing the CR/LF from search.

But be aware, that the multi-word-search-word in data-file may be split between lines. like:

```
find me

i am the text to find
me in this file
```

so a better solution would be:

- read search word by line (remove CR/LF) (normalize it by removing double spaces and not-letters)
- read a chunk from datafile and normalize it too.
- compare or continue by moving the read-position in data left by length of length of search word

Comment: i have tried to use fgets, but it show nothing on the screen

Comment: try again to use fgets() and let you show the result like I suggested; dirctly behind the read, OUTSIDE the `if`